# Git Merge - Incomplete, Missing files and Folders

Tags: git, file, merge, pull

I was trying to merge a dev branch into master.

```
git checkout master    
git pull . dev
```

Everything seemed to go well, although there were conflicts I fixed these and commited. But when I checked this newly merged working tree is missing a lot of folders and files from dev.

```
git status  // Shows conflicts & doesn't list some files/folders.    
git commit -a 

Created commit 55ffdd1: Merge branch 'dev' into master  

git diff dev --name-status
```

Produces:

```
D       folders/lm.gif
D       folders/lmh.gif
...
```

So the files/folders that didn't show up on 'git status'. It also didn't show up at the end when I fixed the merged conflicts.

Also when I try to merge again it says:

```
git merge dev    
Already up-to-date.
```

Yet the master branch clearly is missing files/folders from the dev branch. Why is that? Shouldn't that folder and all it's contents be added? 'folders' is being tracked on the dev branch, so shouldn't it have gotten pulled over when I did the merge?

When there was a merge conflict earlier did git stop the merge process and skipped a bunch of files/folders?

The dev branch had quite a lot of changes, could I have messed something up with git in the past that now certain files/folders wouldn't have merged?

(When I first created the dev branch I didn't know what I was doing and did crazy things like reset, reverts etc.)

Hoping one of you git guru's here on stack overflow knows the answer. :)

Thanks,
Quang

---

### Answer

Thanks Walter, Yes this is what happened.

After doing some investigating I found out it was a little complicated what happened. It turned out that.

1. dev branched from master, it had all the files.
2. A third branch, lets call it "cleaned", branched off of dev.
3. cleaned branch deleted all the files.
4. cleaned branch merged (or something?) with master. At this point the files were deleted off of master. And the 'cleaned' branch disappeared.
5. on dev, the files are still there and I continued adding to this branch, editing files for quite some time.
6. dev merged with master and all the files that was deleted previously by cleaned were gone.

Hope this helped someone besides me who learned quite a lot about how to use git log, git show, git reflog trying to debug what happened.

Thanks!

### How to Fix

So this is what I did to merge all of the contents in dev that was previously deleted back onto master.

1. Got all the files/folders that was deleted (on dev but not on the newly merged master) `git diff dev --name-status | grep D > deleted_files`
2. Output list of all files and folders `git log --name-status > file_history` Gonna be using this to figure out the last updated version of the deleted file.
3. Go through the list of deleted_files one by one, find the the most updated version in file_history and restore it. Example: `git checkout 25b8a44 view.php` 25b8a44... was the commit with the last updated version of view.php. I tried `cherry-pick` and just a straight `git checkout dev view.php` but i found explicitly using the commit id, it merge more of it's history. (Including the commit that cause the file to be deleted in the first place.)
4. Once all the deleted files are back a quick check `git diff dev --name-status | grep D` shows that all files are copied over. Then like Walter said an ammend commit `git commit --amend` :)

Comment: You can actually do `cat deleted_files | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs -I haha git checkout develop haha` which is more faster. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Please move your answer into an answer post.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It sounds like git thinks that the missing files were deleted on the master at some point between where it branches from dev and the pre-merge head.  That's the only reason I can think of for why git would silently drop tracked files during a merge.

Unfortunately, I don't know a good way to fix that.  I'd probably just re-add all the deleted files from the dev branch manually (or with a little bit of bash scripting), and then to a `git commit --amend` to revise the merge commit to include them.

Comment: Yes this is what happened.

After doing some investigating I found out it was a little complicated what happen. It turned out that.

Look above for explanation.

Comment: another solution is to mixed reset to the time before the files were deleted in the branch, then merge, and force push the new history. Everyone might need to revert to a previous commit and re-pull if they you had committed the bad merge and they pulled it.

Comment: Happened to me too after using `git revert -m 1 commit` to revert some merges. Only way I found was by manually comparing the differences and add them manually. Conclusion: Never use `git revert` again.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such a situation - use merge with --no-ff option (merge without fast forwarding). More details about --no-ff flag here https://betterdev.blog/turn-off-git-fast-forward-merge/, https://hackr.io/blog/difference-between-git-merge-and-git-merge-no-ff

In general - fast forward merge is suitable for merging simple features or bug fixes, but in case when branches developed separately for a while (ex. big feature or release branches) - you need to avoid it.

So for your case it'll look like:

```
git fetch origin cleaned
git fetch origin dev
git fetch origin master

git checkout master
git merge --no-ff origin/cleaned
```

fix conflicts and commit

at this moment some files are removed (changes from cleaned) from master but still present (and maybe modified) in dev

```
git merge --no-ff dev
```

here you'll face conflicts on files which were removed from master but received from dev again, need to fix them by accepting changes from dev

```
commit changes and push
```

Eventually you'll receive transparent history and if you missed or lost something while resolving conflicts - you can easily restore it using merge commit containing 3 commit merge info.