# Git merges removing files

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

It's the second time this happens, when I'm doing a merge I later realized some files that were in the branch being merged are no longer in the branch being merged to.

The latest example is we have a feature branch which I've been merging the changes in from the main dev branch, we lost a lot of files after a merge and they are not present in the feature branch now.

1. Why does this happen?
2. What's the best way to get these files? I'm thinking of manually adding them.

here is a description of the repo when the files were lost:

964495c is where the files were lost, it is a merge of the remote branch with a local branch.
d1c457a is a merge from the main dev branch into the feature branch.

When I do a diff of these two branches I see the files I have lost as being removed, but they were never set to remove. This wasn't my merge so I'm not sure if it was user error, but I  need to figure out the best way to include these files in my feature branch...

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472804/git-merge-incomplete-missing-files-and-folders

Comment: Yes, the cause I think is a little different as I'm sure the files were not deleted between merge.. The weird thing is these files are referenced in the project files just fine, it was just the physical file that went missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### An answer to part 1

I don't have enough information here to tell you what *did* happen ... but here is how to see what *should* happen (or have happened), on a `git merge ...`.  We can see from the image above that `964495c` is a merge and one if its parent commits is `d1c457a` (the yellow dot and line).  We cannot see its other parent commit—the other parent is down the other end of the purple line.  (One line is, I imagine, branch `dev` and the other is branch `feature`.)

[**Edit**: per comment, the first-parent is `29a7b67` (on branch `feature`), and second is `d1c457a` (on branch `dev` as expected).]

The first thing `git merge` does is find the "merge base".  So, in a shell command window, find the two parent-IDs:

```
$ git rev-parse 964495c^1
29a7b67...
$ git rev-parse 964495c^2
d1c457a...
```

<s>(I'm partly guessing here, based on colors, that `d1c457a` is the second-parent, i.e., the thing being merged-in, rather than the thing merged-into—not that it matters too much, the merge result should be the same either way).</s> [**Edit**: confirmed]

Now, using the two commit IDs produced above, find the merge-base.  <s>For simplicity I'll assume the first command produced `1234567...`</s> Per comment, this is `8967ae7...`

```
$ git merge-base 29a7b67 d1c457a
8967ae7...
```

You now have three commit IDs.  Let's re-do the above with shell variables, <s>just so that I don't have to guess at the commit-IDs any more</s> since the symbolic names might help:

```
$ id_into=$(git rev-parse 964495c^1)
$ id_from=$(git rev-parse 964495c^2)
$ id_base=$(git merge-base $id_into $id_from)
```

Now shell variables `$id_base`, `$id_from`, and `$id_into` hold the commit ID of the merge-base, the tip of the branch being merged-from,<sup>1</sup> and the ID of the commit just before `964495c` itself (the original tip of branch `feature` when the merge was being done).

Using these, we can see what `git merge` is asked to merge, by doing two `git diff`s.  (The next bit assumes Unix/Linux/Mac shell redirection.)

```
$ git diff -M50% $id_base $id_into > /tmp/existing_changes
$ git diff -M50% $id_base $id_from > /tmp/new_changes
```

The first diff finds out "what has happened on this branch, i.e., `feature` since the other branch `dev` diverged from it".  The second diff finds out "what has happened on the other branch `dev` since it diverged from this branch, i.e., `feature`".

The `merge` command then attempts to combine these two.  Wherever `dev` has any change:

- if the change is to add a new file, add the new file (unless `feature` has also added it: then we probably have a conflict that requires manual resolution)
- if the change is to rename a file, rename the file (again unless `feature` has it already)
- **if the change is to remove a file, remove the file**
- if the change is to add or remove some lines from a file, do that here (unless `feature` has it already, in which case, ignore the change; or if we can't find those exact lines with the same contents, then we have a conflict—this conflict case includes the case where the file was removed in `feature`).

I have bolded the case where `git merge` *should* remove a file.  If the merge-from branch (`dev`) removed that file since the merge-base, `git merge` will quietly remove the file from the merge result.

---

Now, with all that said, if whoever is doing the merge uses `--no-commit`, or if there is a conflict, the merge stops after doing whatever it can, and whoever is doing the merge has a chance to make *additional* changes.  In the case of merge conflicts, this is of course where the person doing the merge must resolve the conflicts.  However, the person doing the merge can use `--no-commit` to get here even without conflicts.  In any case, at this point, the person doing the merge can remove files, add files, and modify files.  When he or she (ok, let's use "they" :-) ) ... when they are done, they `git commit` the result, and that made commit `964495c...`.

---

<sup>1</sup>At least, it's what was the tip of `dev` at the time: `dev` might have grown a bit since then, just as `feature` has in fact grown since then.

### An answer to part 2

There is not necessarily a single best way to get the missing files back, but it's easy to check out files from a particular commit.  Here the obvious one to use is `29a7b67` (aka `$id_from` above, the tip of `feature` when whoever did the merge, did the merge):

```
$ git checkout 29a7b67 -- path/to/file
```

(List multiple files, or one or more directories, to get more files, or every file in the directory, out of that commit-ID.)  This puts the files into the work-tree *and* the index, as of the state they were in at that commit-ID, so that the next `git commit` will include them in that state.

(You can of course edit them and `git add` the result to make changes if needed.)

Comment: Here is a longer screenshot of the workflow...
http://i.imgur.com/PH6jaq2.png

Merge base is: 8967ae7
Parents are d1c457a(from) and 29a7b67(to).

When I do a diff of 29a7b67 which should be the "to" to the base, I see the files removed.. Does this mean that the files were removed in this merge?. If this is the case, I guess the developer would have to had somehow remove them from a merge..

Comment: OK, let me edit the above a bit.  Meanwhile where you say "do a diff of `29a7b67`": diff `29a7b67` vs what?  Git diffs are mostly pairwise (the exception is "combined diff" which is complicated but not relevant here).

Comment: a diff of 29a7b67 vs the merge-base.. After doing the twi diff(base vs to and base vs from) I can see why the files would have been removed. However it leaves me at the same place where I was, WHY were they removed by the previous merge. One theory is it was done by the dev, as it is a merge without the default merge message, I feel maybe they removed some files and treated it as a regular commit. I hope this makes sense, I'm fairly new to git and learning as I go..

Comment: Ultimately git can only get you so far; if someone does a merge and gets a conflict (or uses `--no-commit`) and "fixes" the conflict wrong, you get a nonsense commit.  Plus it can only auto-resolve things in terms of "ok, I can add/remove this textually", it doesn't really understand any of what it's doing.

Comment: Yep.. I think ultimately this was user error... Thanks, you helped me a ton with further understanding of the merge process!!