# How to understand why git merge removed a file?

Tags: git, version-control

I've read [Git merges removing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555648/git-merges-removing-files) but it didn't help understanding. I believe there was (and is) only one master branch.

```
% git diff 7348fe7 11b0744
diff --git "a/site.com.gpg" "b/site.com.gpg"
deleted file mode 100644
index 03fc298..0000000
--- "a/site.com.gpg"
+++ /dev/null
```

```
% git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline
...
*   11b0744 Merge branch 'master' of ssh://host/~/.password-store
|\  
| * 7348fe7 Edit password for site.com using editor.
| * e21adcd Add generated password for site.com.
...
```

```
% git show 11b0744
commit 11b0744d63182148c5daa9d719159f0006bd2140
Merge: ff88689 7348fe7
Author: a <a@host>
Date:   Sat Jun 27 11:36:28 2020 +0300

    Merge branch 'master' of ssh://host/~/.password-store

diff --cc "site.com.gpg"
index 682f8f3,03fc298..0000000
deleted file mode 100644,100644
--- "a/site.com.gpg"
+++ /dev/null
```

Comment: what's output of `git diff ff88689 11b0744` in regards to that file? Have you tried to find merge-base as described in that thread you linked?

Comment: merge-base is just 7348fe7


```
% git diff ff88689 11b0744
diff --git "a/site.com.gpg" "b/site.com.gpg"
deleted file mode 100644
index 682f8f3..0000000
--- "a/site.com.gpg"
+++ /dev/null
...
```

Comment: Sorry, don't get it. Was 7348fe7 a direct descendant of ff88689?

Comment: What's the problem? The file exists in 7448fe7 and not in 11b0744? The file must have been deleted between (the common ancestors of 7448fe7 and _the other parent_ of 11b0744) and _the other parent_ of 11b077 (in other words, in the other branch, the one we don't see)... or it was deleted _by hand_ in the merge commit itself. What is the question?